# WIPS Alert: Reason "NoProfile" detected on AP

Tags: cisco, wireless, troubleshooting

I'm trying to understand how I should act on a trap I'm receiving from our WLC

```
WIPS Alert: Reason "NoProfile" detected on AP MAC: 00:1a:30:00:00:00, AP Name: West128_c3602i
```

My searches for the meaning of this message have not turned up anything useful.

We have:

- WLC5508, Version 7.4.121.0
- APs in [monitor mode](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/wireless/technology/wips/deployment/guide/WiPS_deployment_guide.html#wp43469), WIPS sub-mode
- AP model is c3602i
- This is a new deployment, so NCS Prime / MSE are not operational yet

The AP in question are joined to the default "WLAN AP Group"; however, other "local" mode APs are in a dedicated group.

- Why is the WLC alarming on this condition?  Is there a real problem or is this just noise?
- How should I resolve the issue?

Comment: Does the alert only occur when the AP boots? If not, how frequent does it occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a shot in the dark but it sounds like you [need Prime configured](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/wireless/mse/3350/7-4/wIPS_Configuration/Guide/7_4_MSE_wIPS/7_4_MSE_wIPS_chapter_01001.html) so you can setup a profile for wIPS. The alert is telling you that a profile is not configured yet.

I have not gotten this far in my own deployment of some 5508s/PI so I cannot say for certain.

EDIT: Reading further, the default profiles are also supplied by Prime, not the WLC:

> By default, the mobility services engine and corresponding wIPS access
>   points inherit the default wIPS profile from the Prime Infrastructure.

Comment: Thank you for answering; I will need some time to validate this myself... it might take a while since I already set the Prime implementation aside in favor of more pressing priorities

Comment: No problem. I am able to reproduce with a 2602E on my lab WLC. Since the 5508s came in today I will be running a lab with PI this weekend. I'll let you know if this resolves the error. `Tue Jul 8 01:05:29 2014 WIPS Alert: Reason "NoProfile" detected on AP MAC: 68:86:a7:XX:XX:XX, AP Name: 2600E` Keep in mind, I am using 7.6 in my lab for 802.11ac support (we're getting 2700/3700 APs next week).